# RStudio not loading RevoScaleR on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, revoscaler

**Long story short:**
Calling `rxImport()` works fine in a Terminal R session but fails when using RStudio, despite using the same installation of R.

**Setup:**
I'd like to use RevoScaleR functions like rxImport(...) on Ubuntu. I have an installation of RStudio and R done through package manager.

I've installed MS Rclient following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/machine-learning-server/r-client/install-on-linux).
Everything seems to work as I can run in the terminal:

```
/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/bin/R$ ./R

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
...
Microsoft R Open 3.4.3
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft

Loading Microsoft R Client packages, version 3.4.3.0097. 
Microsoft R Client limits some functions to available memory.
See: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=799476 for information
about additional features.
...
Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 2 cores).
Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2018-01-01.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

> R.home()
[1] "/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R"
> rxImport()
Error in rxImport() : 'inData' must be specified.
```

So the function is loaded and available by default. Now I tell the RStudio to use this installation of R by adding the following at the end of `~/.profile` :

```
RSTUDIO_WHICH_R="/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/bin/R/R"
```

**Error:**
When I run `rstudio` I get a R console in the IDE saying:

```
> R.home()
[1] "/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R"
> rxImport()
Error in rxImport() : could not find function "rxImport"
```

**Possible causes**
I've found [some threads](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-r/issues/9) with people complaining about MS packages not dealing properly with `~` and working directory (i.e. on a remote server), `setwd()` doesn't solve my issue, though.

Do you have any ideas on how to get RevoScaleR to work with RStudio? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer I got from Github:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2455#issuecomment-375327109

try setting

```
R_LIBS_SITE=/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/libraries/RServer
```

in

```
/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/etc/Renviron
```