# Cannot find ‘RevoScaleR’ in Microsoft R Client

Tags: r, rstudio-server, microsoft-r, r-server

I have installed Microsoft R Client. When I run R from shell, I get

```
Microsoft R Open 3.4.3
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft

Loading Microsoft R Client packages, version 3.4.3.0097. 
Microsoft R Client limits some functions to available memory.
See: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=799476 for information
about additional features.

Type 'readme()' for release notes, privacy() for privacy policy, or
'RevoLicense()' for licensing information.

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 36 cores).
Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2018-01-01.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.
```

However, when I run R from Rstudio-server, I get only

```
Microsoft R Open 3.4.3
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 36 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2018-01-01.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.
```

The system only has one copy of R, and it together with the library path are correctly specified in `rserver.conf`

```
cat /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf 
# Server Configuration File
rsession-which-r=/usr/bin/Revo64
rsession-ld-library-path=/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/libraries/RServer
```

Inside the Rstudio R environment, the library path is there

```
>.libPaths()
[1] "/home/xyz/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4"   
[2] "/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/library"
```

However, `RevoScaleR` does not load automatically. When I try to load it manually, I get

```
> library(RevoScaleR)
Fehler in library(RevoScaleR) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘RevoScaleR’
```

Anybody has an idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179151/rstudio-not-loading-revoscaler-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer from Github:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2455#issuecomment-375327109

setting

```
R_LIBS_SITE=/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/libraries/RServer
```

in

```
/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/etc/Renviron
```